# Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` supplied to `CSSTransition`, expected one of type [function]

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, веб-программирование, extend

Я только учу React, столкнулся с такой проблемой: при попытке добавить тег **CSSTransition** и у меня
такая предупреждение ( Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` supplied to `CSSTransition`, expected one of type [function]. ) и за этого мой код дальше не работать помогите, пожалуйста.

I only teach React, faced with such a problem: when trying to add tag **CSSTransition** and I have
This warning ( Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop ¹childrenː supplied to ¹CSSTransition ī, expected one of type [function]. ) and for this my code further do not work help, please.

Код / code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { TransitionGroup, CSSTransition } from 'react-transition-group';
import Post from './Post';

const PostsItems = props => {

    if (!props.props.length) {
        return <p style={{
            textAlign: 'center',
            marginTop: '30px'
        }}>На данный момент постов нет</p>
    }

    return (
        <div className='posts'>
            <TransitionGroup>
                {props.props.map(postInfo => {
                    <CSSTransition
                        key={postInfo.id}
                        timeout={500}
                        classNames="post"
                    >
                        return <Post date={postInfo.date} infoValue={postInfo} key={postInfo.id} fromCreater={postInfo.fromCreater} deletePostFn={props.remove}/>
                    </CSSTransition>
                })}
            </TransitionGroup>
        </div>
    );
}

export default PostsItems;
```

Comment: Попробуйте убрать return из map

Comment: Я пробовал убрать однако это тоже не помогает, не знаю в чем дело

Comment: @Zaccal получилось решить?У меня такая же проблема...